# Inserting a row in Google spreadsheet: Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am unable to add row to an existing spreadsheet.
I'm trying the steps from here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data
The following line throws the exception below:

```
row = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead.

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
at TestGoogle.main(TestGoogle.java:93)
```

The full story short: The above example is quite similar with the code in the application that I need to fix, and the application worked some times ago.
I managed to pass the OAuth2 authentication.

Comment: "Blank rows cannot be written" is the error, is the row blank?  ... Adding a list row docs https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

Comment: No, the row is not blank. I tried the exact code from the above mentioned doc sample at the "Add a list row" section.

Comment: List feed was a bit messy to use, I switched to cell feed long ago. I don't remember the details, but I had to experiment with it to understand what it allows. I know you need row Headers and not sure if it allows blank cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get this error message is probably because you're trying to add to a blank spreadsheet and the header doesn't exist.

If we add the headers first, then it should work.

Using the "Add a list row" example from the documentation you linked; add the headers like this before adding a list row

```
CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(worksheet.CellFeedLink);
CellFeed cellFeed = service.Query(cellQuery);

CellEntry cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 1, "firstname");
cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 2, "lastname");
cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 3, "age");
cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 4, "height");
cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
```

Then the list entry example should add to the spreadsheet properly

```
// Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
ListFeed listFeed = service.Query(listQuery);

// Create a local representation of the new row.
ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "firstname", Value = "Joe" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "lastname", Value = "Smith" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "age", Value = "26" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "height", Value = "176" });

// Send the new row to the API for insertion.
service.Insert(listFeed, row);
```